# Table with double line and thick border

Tags: tables

I want a table like the one in the following figure.
[image]
It has a thick border and a double line before total row.

I get the following result with MWE. Note that the border does not have a thicker border exactly at the double line. Even if I use \hhline{|==|} the border is not a thicker one.

How can I get the result I want?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  % \caption{Table}
    \begin{tabular}{V{4}l|rV{4}}
    \hline
    \hlineB{3}
    \multicolumn{1}{V{4}c|}{\textbf{Item}} & \multicolumn{1}{cV{4}}{\textbf{Price}} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    A &         900.00  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    B &         441.52  \bigstrut\\
    \hhline{==}
    Total  &     1,341.52  \bigstrut\\
    \hlineB{3}
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \hlineB{3}
    \textbf{Total After Tax} &     1,850.37  \bigstrut\\
    \hlineB{3}
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:tablerev}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean you don't want there to be a gap?

Comment: @JasperHabicht That's it. No gap and thick border (between Row B and Total).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{ 
        colspec = { l r },
        row{1} = { c, font=\bfseries },
        cell{Z}{1} = { font=\bfseries },
        hlines,
        hline{1,Y,Z} = {2pt},
        hline{X} = {2}{-}{},
        hline{Y} = {2}{-}{2pt},
        vlines,
        vline{1,Z} = {1-X}{2pt, belowpos=1},
        vline{1,Z} = {Y-Z}{2pt}
    }
    Item            &    Price \\
    A               &   900.00 \\
    B               &   441.52 \\
    Total           & 1,341.52 \\
    Total After Tax & 1,850.37 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` but not very easy (it's easier with `tabularray`...).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document} 

\begin{NiceTabular}{l!{\vrule}r}[cell-space-limits=3pt,rules/width=0.2pt]
    \RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block[draw,line-width=1pt]{4-2}{}
    \Block[c]{}{Item} & \Block[c]{}{Price} \\
\hline
    A                 &   900.00 \\
\hline
    B                 &   441.52 \\
\hline\hline
    Total             & 1,341.52 \\ 
\noalign{\vspace*{-3mm}} \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\ 
\Block[draw,line-width=1pt]{1-2}{}
    Total After Tax   & 1,850.37 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]